# Show Alt text in div with same class (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, append

I'd like to show my imgs alt text and my divs being the same class. The way I'm doing it just shows the alt of the first image on all divs, someone can help me?

my code:

```
<div id="tela">
    <div class="folha"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Rondo Alla turca"></div>
    <div class="folha"><img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Fur Elise"></div>
    <div class="folha"></div>
    <div class="folha"></div>
    <div class="folha"></div>
    <div class="folha"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var alt = $('#tela .folha img').attr('alt');
        var p = $('<p></p>');
        var div = $('.folha');
        $('.folha:has(img)').append(p);
        $('p',this).addClass('title').text(alt);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you want to append the text? Under the image?

Comment: Yes, in my css it will appear under the div with the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop thru the images using `each()`.

Here is a snippet.

```js
$('#tela .folha img').each(function() {
  var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
  $(this).parent().append('<p class="title">' + alt + '</p>')
});
```

```css
.folha {
  margin-bottom : 5px;
  background-color : red;
  padding : 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tela">
  <div class="folha"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Rondo Alla turca"></div>
  <div class="folha"><img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Fur Elise"></div>
  <div class="folha"></div>
  <div class="folha"></div>
  <div class="folha"></div>
  <div class="folha"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help @BrunoF.Cardoso :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop, for example using `.each()`, and `this` to refer to the specific element being looped over:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.folha:has(img)').each(function() {
    var alt = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
    var p = $('<p></p>').addClass('title').text(alt);
    $(this).append(p);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tela">
  <div class="folha"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Rondo Alla turca"></div>
  <div class="folha"><img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Fur Elise"></div>
  <div class="folha"></div>
  <div class="folha"></div>
  <div class="folha"></div>
  <div class="folha"></div>
</div>
```